# Extracting Tables From Email, innerHTML err 91

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

have been googling around for a code to extract tables from emails and am trying to adapt the codes by changing early binding to late binding.

However, the code seems to bug out at the objHTML.body.innerHTML = objMailItem.HTMLBody line.

Code seems to run alright when used in Excel but bugs out when I run on outlook vba.

any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
Public Function ExtractOutlookTables(objMailItem As Object) As Object

Dim vTable As Variant    
Dim objHTML As Object: Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlFile")
Dim objEleCol As Object

objHTML.Body.innerHTML = objMailItem.HTMLBody ' <<error line>>

With objHTML
    objHTML.Body.innerHTML = objMailItem.HTMLBody
    Set objEleCol = .getElementsByTagName("table")
End With

'import in Excel
Dim x As Long, y As Long

For x = 0 To objEleCol(0).Rows.Length - 1
    For y = 0 To objEleCol(0).Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
        vTable(x, y) = objEleCol(0).Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
    Next y
Next x

ErrorHandler:
    Set objHTML = Nothing: Set objEleCol = Nothing
End Function



''
' Function that returns a dictionary of arrays of strings, each representing a table in the email; key = 0 represents the most recent table
' @param    objMailItem object representing an Outlook Mail Item object
' @return   Dictionary of arrays of strings where each key represents the index of the table (0 being the most recent table)
' @remarks  Please note that index 0 = table in the most recent email conversation
' @see      none
Public Function fnc_ExtractTablesFromMailItem(objMailItem As Object) As Object
    Dim objHTMLDoc As Object: Set objHTMLDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    Dim dicTables As Object: Set dicTables = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim arrTable() As String
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim intCounter As Integer: intCounter = 0
    objHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objMailItem.htmlbody
    ' Loop through each table in email
    For Each objTable In objHTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
        ReDim arrTable(objTable.Rows.Length - 1, objTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length - 1)
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable.Rows.Length - 1
            Set rw = objTable.Rows(lngRow)
            For lngCol = 0 To rw.Cells.Length - 1
                ' Ignore any problems with merged cells etc
                On Error Resume Next
                arrTable(lngRow, lngCol) = rw.Cells(lngCol).innerText ' Store each table in 1 array
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        dicTables(intCounter) = arrTable ' Store each array as a dictionary item
        intCounter = intCounter + 1
    Next objTable
    Set fnc_ExtractTablesFromMailItem = dicTables
    ' Garbage collection
    Set dicTables = Nothing: Set objTable = Nothing: Set objHTMLDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Learn [ask] and [mcve]. It's only a 5 minute read and it'll save you hours. We want to help, but we need context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the code that is calling the function.  You should post that code.

If the only thing that you actual want from `objMailItem` is it's `HTMLBody` then `objMailItem As Object` should be removed from function signature should and replaced with `HTMLBody as String`.

You must be missing a couple of lines of code; because `vTable`was never allocated and will throw a type mismatch error the way the function is written.

You should also wrap your test whether `objEleCol is Nothing` before you try and use it.

Here I pass the MailItem to `fnc_ExtractTablesFromMailItem`  from `Application_ItemSend` to in Outlook.  There are no errors.

[image]

[image]

The `Application_NewMail` and `Application_NewMailEx` events do not recieve `MailItems` as parameters.  How are you retrieving the `MailItem` that you are passing into your function?

[image]

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for your reply! the function's actually not the full function but I am not too sure how I can use code markup in comments to post an extension to the code. My original intention was to return a dictionary of arrays, where each array represents 1 table from the email (as the email could contain multiple emails). Should i start a new thread with a full code or post a reply to my answer? I have the working code in excel but however when I port it over to outlook it stops working...sorry to trouble!

Comment: There is no need.  You error is that objMailItem is not set properly.  Do you use the object objMailItem or just it's HTMLBody?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply! i suspect i just need the HTML body. But my objMailItem is passed directly from the new mail event...is it possible that it is not set correctly? Thanks again and sorry to trouble!

Comment: It would be better just to send the HTMLBody.  Do you get the error from all items?  The Application_NewMail itself doesn't reference a mailitem; what is your code that sets this reference?

Comment: Hey Thomas, sorry was caught up in some other automation! hmm I pass the entire mail item just in case i need to manipulate the object further....i have edited the code to reflect the latest code that I am currently using myself in excel...but when i replicate this function in outlook it seems to bug out as earlier mentioned....the objHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML does not seem to work in outlook

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your functions.  Can you post your `Application_NewMail` code?